# Linking to the new Joomla 2.5 Controller

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

As many of you know the controller in Joomla 2.5 changed from

```
// Create the controller
$classname  = 'mycomponentController'.$controller;
$controller = new $classname( );

// Perform the Request task
$controller->execute( JRequest::getVar('task'));

// Redirect if set by the controller
$controller->redirect();
```

to something along the lines of

```
// Get an instance of the controller prefixed by the component
$controller = JController::getInstance('mycomponent');

// Perform the Request task
$controller->execute(JRequest::getCmd('task'));

// Redirect if set by the controller
$controller->redirect();
```

Now in Joomla 1.5 as well as by using the table you could run a task by running the link

```
index.php?option=com_mycomponent&controller=specificcontroller&task=randomtask
```

However this style of link doesn't work with the new controller - does anyone know how to format this link in Joomla 2.5 if you're using the new controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine task and controller so that it'll call the task of the specified controller.These will be `.(dot)` seperated. try this-

```
index.php?index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=viewname&task=specificcontroller.randomtask
```

Read More - http://docs.joomla.org/JController_and_its_subclass_usage_overview

Comment: Thanks! Is the view=viewname required?